# Any patterns on how to horizontally scale a service process that subscribes to Exchange Web Services?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, horizontal-scaling

I'd like to get your ideas as to how I can make my service process scale horizontally by being able to run it across multiple servers. It is a Windows service written in C#, and its purpose in life is to subscribe to our company's Exchange Web Service (EWS) so that it gets notified (via HTTP callback) whenever there's a new incoming email message. The service then gets the email message, processes it, sends a reply if possible, then goes back to sleep and waits for the next incoming email.

If I run it on more than one machine, I can either have all of them subscribing to EWS notification, or only one of them. If I have all of them subscribe, I am kind of hesitant because it might add burden to our MS Exchange infrastructure. Also this will result in all machines receiving and processing the email. I wouldn't want the sender to receive a reply N times (where N is the number of servers in the farm) for a given request message! Now if I have only one machine subscribing to EWS, that exposes me to a single point of failure.

I'd like to get your suggestions on how to address this. I'd love to have multiple servers process incoming messages by distributing email messages among them (perhaps I'll have to do this by making use of a message queueing server). Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Depends if you are scaling for reliability or throughput.

If reliability, you can have a primary and a standby process.  The primary process subscribes and processes all emails.  The standby process exchanges keep-alive messages with the primary and takes over as primary if the keep-alive times out.

If throughput, then a message queue mechanism , as you suggested, may be a good approach.  You could run primary and standby as above, but the primary just pulls emails into a queue.  A farm of message processors pulls off the queue.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In this particular instance, reliability is more important. As for having a primary and standby -- what design pattern(s) can be applied here so that the servers in the farm can detect if the primary has gone down, and if so, how do they "elect" the new primary? These are the patterns I'm looking for.

Comment: A simple solution uses a shared, reliable storage medium with an exclusive locking mechanism (e.g. redundant database) which records 'last primary active time stamp' and 'primary process id'. Primary updates this, processes read it to determine if they're primary. When time stamp goes stale, process tries to write its process id to claim primary. Much more sophistication is possible (e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paxos_%28computer_science%29) but simple may be good enough for your situation.